# Reading binary data in python, sending it over restful api and saving the file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, binary

I have binary data that looks like this:

```
MZ����K=�@���K=�ޡ���g������a;�������������¡�����ء�����������{�����<��������o�������������쁡�����������k�������������Rich����
```

When opened raw.

I'm reading the binary using Python:

```
data = open(path_to_watch+filename,  "rb").read()
```

When I send it to my node.js server it looks like this:

```
 MZ90%00%03%00%00%00%04%00%00%00%FF%FF%00%00%B8%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%40%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%008%01%00%00%0E%1F%BA%0E%00%B4%09%CD%21%B8%01L%CD%21This+program+cannot+be+run+in+DOS+mode.%0D%0D%0A%24%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%BB%C0%92%BE%FF%A1%FC%ED%FF%A1%FC%ED%FF%A1%FC%EDK%3d
```

I'm trying to save it but for the life of me I can't get it to match the original file, filesize or to work when run:

```
data = req.body["file"];
data = data.replace("%", " ");
var buff = new Buffer(data.length);
for (x=0; x<data.length;x++){
  buff[x] = data[x];
}
fs.writeFile("test.exe", data,"binary");
```

I don't know what the second format is but I'm sure it's an interpretation of binary that I need to convert, I just can't figure out for the life of me what to google anymore.

Comment: It looks like url-encoded bytes to me.

Comment: decodeURI() says it's malformed but you might be right

Comment: `decodeURI()` is looking for an entire URI though. Try `decodeURIComponent()`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys I finally figured out wtf to do!

In Python, I sent the data as an octet stream using the requests library as a "PUT".

I did this by reading as binary like so:

```
data = open(path_to_watch+filename,  "rb").read()
```

and then sending the data using the requests library like this:

```
response= requests.request("PUT", URL, data=data,  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

So far so good?

On the Node JS side I used the "stream" library built into node along with filesystem.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');



  app.put("/", function (req, res) {
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream("output.bin");

    req.on('data', function(data){
      wstream.write(data);
    })

    req.on('end', () =>{
      wstream.end();
    })


    res.status(200).send({ message: 'File recieved' });
  };
```

Hope someone else doesn't have to spend 7 hours debugging like I did :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp):

```
data = decodeURIComponent(req.body["file"]);
var buff = new Buffer(data.length);
for (x=0; x<data.length;x++){
  buff[x] = data[x];
}
fs.writeFile("test.exe", data,"binary");
```

Comment: In your Python code, what do you get when you print `data`?

Comment: it looks like this
`\x08\xe4\x87\x92\xcf\xe4\x84\x8f\xff\xf3\xa4\xb0\xfe\xff\xc6\xd2\xff\xff\xc6\xd2\xff\x`

I'm also sending the information with a header that is x-www-form-urlencoded and sending a json with one of the fields set to `data`

Comment: Odd... that doesn't start with "MZ" like the other two. What were you using to see the binary data that's in your question? (the one with MZ and a bunch of � glyphs)

Comment: Oh sorry, the text is super duper long. this is just an example of the format and a randomly cut piece of it. I'm using VSCode

Comment: btw I got a new buffer thingy

`Buffer 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00`